# Converting binary string to int in C

Tags: c, string, binary, int

I'm converting a binary string to an int in C. I wrote a code and it compiles but it's not doing what I want it to, which is converting a 16-bit binary string to an int. Here's my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main() {

        char input[16];
        int result;
        char c;
        int i;
        i = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int a = 1;

        puts("Enter a 16-bit binary value to return its integer value");
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
            input[i++];
        }

        for(count = strlen(input) - 1; count >=0; count--)
        {
            if(input[count] == '1')
            {
                result += a;
            }
            a <<= 1;
        }
        printf("The binary %s is integer %d", input, result);

        return 0;

    }
```

When I run it, it asks me to enter a 16 bit binary value. If I enter "0000000000000010" it prints "The binary @@ is integer 2007885296" instead of 2. What am I doing wrong?

I'm compiling and running this code on a Linux server through PuTTY.exe and I'm editing this code in vi, not sure if that makes any difference.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1)  `char input[16];` --> `char input[17];` 2) `input[i++];` --> `input[i++]=c;` and `input[i]=0;` after loop.

Comment: 3) `int result;` --> `int result=0;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I think the problem does have something to do with the variable result. I did what you suggested and the program always printed 0 regardless of the binary string I put in. I'm just not sure how to fix it. I think result needs to be outside of the if statement maybe?

Comment: The main cause is (2) `input[i++];`  this isn't assign.

Comment: [fixed DEMO](http://ideone.com/iMKlyw)

Comment: regarding this line: `while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {`  to avoid overflowing the input[] array, the line should be: `while( i <16 && (c = getchar()) != '\n') {`

Comment: the function: `getchar()` returns an `int`, so this line: `char c;` would be better written as `int c`;

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`   I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`.   Then fix those warnings.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks so much! That helped a lot

Comment: @user3629249 thanks so much! That helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code cleanly compiles,works correctly, but performs no validation that a user input is only 0s and 1s.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BINARY_LEN (16)

int main( void )
{

    char input[ BINARY_LEN+1 ] = {'\0'};
    int c;
    int i=0;

    puts("Enter a 16-bit binary value to return its integer value\n");

    // EDIT2: increase length to allow for trailing NUL byte
    for( ; i<BINARY_LEN; i++)
    {
        if( (c = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != c)
        {
            input[i] = (char)c;
        }

        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    int result = 0;
    for( int j=0; j<i; j++ )
    {
        // EDIT1: move shift statement to create proper result
        result <<= 1;

        if(input[j] == '1')
        {
            result |= 1;
        }   
    }

    printf("The binary %s is integer %d", input, result);

    return 0;

}
```

here is an example run of the code:

```
Enter a 16-bit binary value to return its integer value

101
The binary 101 is integer 5
```

and

```
Enter a 16-bit binary value to return its integer value

11000
The binary 11000 is integer 24
```

Comment: your result become `The binary 101 is integer 10`. also `11000`(2) is `24`. (

Comment: ridiculous... E.g 10000(2) is 16 , 1000(2) is 8. 16 + 8 is 24.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY,   This is odd, the code was working correctly, suddenly it is shifting left once too often.  Code now corrected

Comment: The new code is not correct. Now worse than before.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY,  some intermediate stages of the edit got posted, my fumble finger error for posting the comment before posting the final code

Comment: `char input[ BINARY_LEN ] = {'\0'};` --> `char input[ BINARY_LEN+1 ] = {'\0'};`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY,  Ok, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize `result`, also you don't need the variable `a`

```
result=0;

for(count=0,len=strlen(input); count<len; count++)
    {
        result<<=1;
        if(input[count] == '1')
        {
            result += 1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: wrong, the best this can do it is yield a `result` of 16

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, it was reversing the bit order, now it's fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

input has no null terminator. You read it from the keyboard but you don't add a null at the end.

```
puts("Enter a 16-bit binary value to return its integer value");
while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    input[i++];
}
input[i] = 0; // Add this.
```

and make input [17] so you have a place for the null